# Choose a string based on random number

Tags: php

I am working on a bit of PHP and I've come upon a bit of issues.
I am using PHP to randomly choose a number from 1-360. I am trying to compare the answer to a list of value determined by range.

```
$NumberA = rand(0,180);
$NumberB = rand(0,180);
$NumberC = $NumberA + $NumberB;

if ($NumberC = range(0,21) {
    $result = "Orange";
}
elseif ($NumberC = range(22,42) {
    $result = "Red";
}
elseif ($NumberC = range(43,63) {
    $result = "Blue";
}
           //This goes on for a while               ...
else {
   $result = "Green";
}

echo = $result;
```

Anytime i do this, the result always assigns the value of "Orange" to $result .

Im sure im doing something wrong here, please help!

Comment: Right now you are doing an assignment(`=`). What you want to do is something like this: `($NumberC >= 0 && $NumberC <= 21)`

Comment: You should also be using a switch http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you used just one '=' to compare while it should have been '=='. Second [range()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) generates an array and you cannot compare an integer to an array. Third why generating the range every single time when you can check that `$NumberC` lies between the minimum and the maximum numbers of the range?

Change your code to:

```
$NumberA = rand(0,180);
$NumberB = rand(0,180);
$NumberC = $NumberA + $NumberB;

if ($NumberC >= 0 && $NumberC <= 21) {
    $result = "Orange";
} elseif ($NumberC >= 22 && $NumberC <= 42) {
    $result = "Red";
} elseif ($NumberC >= 43 && $NumberC <= 63) {
    $result = "Blue";
} else {
    $result = "Green";
}

echo $result;
```

Shall work. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks alot! Im such a noob!

Comment: @CoryBell No worries man. Feel free to mark this as an answer if it answered your question. Cheers

Comment: Ok, So that works right, but now when i try to use the Ajax function with Javascript to get the result and pass it to a function, it always results as 0 :\ which im assuming means it cant find the value..

Comment: I cant seem to get ajax to give me the value of the info   // Make get request to the server-side script. `code`
        xhr.open('result',"calculate_prize.php", true);
        xhr.send(''); `code`

Comment: Would you mind showing me the code for ajax to retrieve a value of a var or div in the PHP page? I tried using GET but not sure how to assign the variable to $_GET without a form.